# UITableView Cell With No Selection Animation Still Using Row Select

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView and I'd like to make it so my cells are still selectable, but the animation does not occur. I have implemented the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and in the `insertRowsAtIndexPath` method I have set `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`, however, I still get an animation when attempting to select a cell. How can I remove this animation?

(I am using a custom UITableViewCell class and plan to have my own 'animation' of sorts in the form of a queued async call and an activity view, but I need to get rid of this stock animation first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the cell's `setSelected:animated` (you should already have one) and do not call super's version. Note that that will interfere with the selection state so it'll break when you come to implement your own animation.

At that point, put the call to super back but stop the cell making the hilight by replacing the selectedBackgroundView withe a transparent view. Add this:

```
UIView* selectionFrig = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
selectionFrig.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.selectedBackgroundView = selectionFrig;
```

to your `awakeFromNib` or init code.